# Angular passing variables to HTTP GET

Tags: angular, http

I am new to Angular.

I am trying to send a parameter to a HTTP GET request.

My code looks like this:

```
      for (var i = 0, len = this.recentArtists.topartists.artist.length; i < len && i < historyLimit; i++) {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '?method=artist.getsimilar&mbid=' + this.recentArtists.topartists.artist[i].mbid)
      .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(similarResult => {
        console.log(this.recentArtists.topartists.artist[i]);
```

The log always shows the value corresponding to the last value of 'i'.

I understand that the get request is asynchronous, so I guess that all the loop is processed before the first GET request finishes. But in this case, how can I acces some variable defined before the GET request?

Comment: Use `let i = 0` instead of `var i = 0`

Comment: Thanks. This seems so straightforward and yet I couldn't find one example. You could post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has a "run to completion" model which means that code in the current [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) block will run until it is completed before processing any messages in the event queue. When you do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  someAsync(() => doSomething(i));
}
```

You are actually posting `len` messages to the event queue which will not be executed until the `for` loop completes. This means that `i` will already be incremented to the value of `len` before `doSomething(i)` gets called. `var` declares a variable in execution context.

Instead, you can use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which declares a variable in block scope context which means that `i` keeps its value for each individual block in which it was declared.

---

That being said, rather than use a `for` loop I would suggest some different approaches:

1. Avoid making http calls like this in a loop. If possible, consolidate it to a single call. This will depend on the API you are using.
2. Use `.forEach` or `.map` on the array (`this.recentArtists.topartists.artist`) in this case.

ex:

```
this.recentArtists.topartists.artist.forEach(({ mbid }) => {
  this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}?method=artist.getsimilar&mbid=${mbid}`).pipe(
    map(res => res.json())
  ).subscribe();
});
```

Your use of `res => res.json()` indicates that you are using the older [`HttpModule`](https://angular.io/api/http/HttpModule) instead of [`HttpClientModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) where that step would be unnecessary. I recommend upgrading.

If you must use all of these API calls at once, I recommend that you use RxJS's `forkJoin` to wait for all of the requests to complete at once. For example:

```
forkJoin(...this.recentArtists.topartists.artist.map(({ mbid }) =>
  this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}?method=artist.getsimilar&mbid=${mbid}`).pipe(
    map(res => res.json())
  ))
)).subscribe(console.log);
```